# Dynamically find enum values based on enum name

Tags: c#, reflection, combobox, enums

I have 1 enum declaration of "car_brands" like this :

```
public enum Car_brands
{
    Audi = 1,
    ...
    ...
}
```

and many others enum declarations of each "car_brand" like this

```
public enum Audi
{
    model_a3 = 1,
    model_a4 = 2,
    ...
}
```

I have 2 combobox associated. One associated with the car_brands :

```
 comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(Car_brands.Keys, null);
```

I want the other combobox fill with select brand's enum (exemple Audi's models of Audi Enum).

I try this but it seems not exact...

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string value = comboBox1.Text;   //car brand
Type type = Type.GetType(value);
var brand_models = Enum.GetNames(type.GetType());
                foreach (string enumValue in brand_models)
                    {
                        string brand_model = enumValue;
                        MessageBox.Show(brand_model);
                    }

        }
```

Comment: FYI - you don't need to explicitly set the numbers in your enum incrementally, it's done automatically.

Comment: I use also them as values in the following of my program... thanks

Comment: My point is, if you take away the int assignment they are still going to represent 1, 2, 3... etc. so it's unnecessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "not exact"? Does it work, or does it not work?

Comment: @James, it is easier to look up a value when explicitly set when it represents a value in the database.

Comment: In fact , I get the error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object  on "Type type = Type.GetType(value);"
My problem is that I want declare an enum key as enum type but I don't know how I can do that

Comment: @James Nope, If you remove values it will represent 0,1,2

Comment: @Silvermind could you elaborate on why its *easier* to look it up? The enum will still represent the same integer value. SriramSakthivel yeah you are correct, that was an oversight on my part as I generally would have a default item to represent 0 e.g. Car_Brands.None.

Comment: @James, Having only 1 car brand wouldn't be a problem, having over 100, would be easier to look up.

Comment: @Silverkind sorry still don't understand what difference it makes? Regardless if its set explicitly or not - the value is the same (at least in this circumstance). Obviously if you need *specific* values its different i.e. 100, 200 etc.

Comment: @James, I know that the value remains the same, but if you have a value like 100 in the database, it is easier to look at your code and search the value 100 than to manually count the enum-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a lot of better ways on how to solve your task but this should work under the circumstances you chose:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string value = comboBox1.Text;   //car brand
  Type type = Type.GetType("YOUR_NAMESPACE." + value);
  var brand_models = Enum.GetNames(type);
  foreach (string enumValue in brand_models)
  {
    string brand_model = enumValue;
    MessageBox.Show(brand_model);
  }
}
```

Please read up on the `Type.GetType` documentation ([to be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)) to get the correct solution for your specific class hierarchy and assembly situation.

Comment: Did you provide the actual namespace or just "namespace."? You need to provide the actual namespace.

Comment: I use the actual namespace : 
Type type = Type.GetType("Cars." + value);
It returns always NULL, I read that I must use AssemblyName, is it the solution, how can I do that?

Comment: I assume that the GUI code is in a different assembly than the enumerations. Can you provide the full picture?

Answer (score 3):

```
Type type = Type.GetType("full namespace where you declare enum" + "." + value);
var brand_models = Enum.GetNames(type);
```

in case of nested type you need to use `"+"` instead of `"."`

[C# : having a "+" in the class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443244/c-sharp-having-a-in-the-class-name)

Comment: @Damith I have tested with many options :
Type type = Type.GetType("Cars" + "." + value); or

Type type = Type.GetType("Cars."+value);
but returns me NULL

Comment: @c_conl you are missing the point, when you load the type you need to use the **full** namespace e.g. MyApplication.Cars