# Fully-qualified path for Reference located in another Solution

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

We are using Roslyn Compiler for generating a **Dependency Graph** for a given application code. The application code can span across multiple solutions and can have references between the solutions (ex. Service code in one solution, common business logic in another solution etc.)

For the purpose of generating the Dependency Graph, we would require **fully-qualified name** and **exact path** of all the **custom types refereed** (ones which we have created as our application code).

Roslyn happens to give this information using the **SemanticModel's Symbol Information**.

**Scenario which works**:

SemanticModel's Symbol Information gives the **Location** (path) and **ContainingSymbol** information for any Type **if the type is declared in the same Solution (under some project) in which it is getting used**.

**Scenario which does not work**:

If the refereed Type **is not part of the current solution** but is part of some **other solution** which is getting refereed in the existing solution, then the SemanticModel does not give any Symbol Information which can give the Path and Fully Qualified Name.

Note:

1. We have already tried using the variants of **GetSpeculativeSymbolInfo** and **GetSpeculativeTypeInfo**. But it does not give any information. It just mentions that its a part of MetaData (as if we are using a Type from .NET Class Lib).
2. Following link "[Get fully-qualified metadata name in Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105909/get-fully-qualified-metadata-name-in-roslyn)" gives a direction; but the approach does not work in the context of cross solution references.
3. Have refereed following link: "[Roslyn: get the symbol for a type defined in a third-party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374777/roslyn-get-the-symbol-for-a-type-defined-in-a-third-party-library)". But this is not working as well (or may be we are missing on some thing simple). We were trying to explore the option of using **Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName()**.

Looking forward to some pointers from the Experts.

**EDIT**: Further details

**//Sample Code for Testing**

```
public class TestClass
{
    Student student = new Student();
    Person person = new Person();
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Notes**:

1. **TestClass** is part of project **Project_1** which is in **Solution_1**.
2. TestClass has two members:
    Class **Student** is part of project **Project_2** which is in **Solution_1** and **Project_1** has a Project Reference to **Project_2**.
   Class **Person** is part of project **Project_XYZ** which is in **Solution_XYZ** and **Project1** from **Solution_1** has a dll Reference to **Project_XYZ** from Solution **Solution_XYZ**.

The .dll of **Project_XYZ** is getting created at location "..\Projects\SourceCode\AllBinaries" and "**Project_1**" from **Solution_1** refers the .dll of **Project_XYZ** from this location "..\Projects\SourceCode\AllBinaries"

**Code for getting Symbol Information of the Type**:

```
private void GetSymbolDetails(TypeSyntax typeSyntax)
{
    ISymbol symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(typeSyntax).Symbol; 
   //HERE semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
}
```

**Scenario which works**:
        When the above code is called with input parameter as "IdentifierNameSyntax IdentifierName Student", the "symbol" gives all the required symbol details of "Student" (including fully-qualified name and exact path).

**Scenario which does not work**:
        When the above code is called with input parameter as "IdentifierNameSyntax IdentifierName Person", the "symbol" value is **null**.

Hope I was able to give a better overview of my problem. 
Looking forward to further updates.

Comment: What problems are you having? As long as you can resolve the metadata reference, symbols should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for replying SLaks.

Scenario which does not work:

If the refereed Type is not part of the current solution but is part of some other solution which is getting refereed in the existing solution, then the SemanticModel does not give any Symbol Information which can give the Path and Fully Qualified Name.


So we want a way in which we can get the fully-qualified name and file path of a Type which is declared in another solution and referred in the current code at hand.

Please let me know if you require any other input.

Comment: What exactly does `GetSymbolInfo()` return? Show us your code. **Every** symbol has a fully-qualified name.  Symbols from metadata will not have a path.

Comment: @AbhijitParkhi: you'll probably need to describe how you're getting your Compilations. Also, grab a compilation and call GetDiagnostics() to see if it's building correctly. My gut is telling me that something either in your environment or your code is causing references between compilations to get lost, so the compiler doesn't have symbols to work with.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I solved it by generating a new solution file that contains all the projects, and use that. We also had to change references to dll files to references to the projects that generate those files in all projects. I don't have that code around right now though, sorry.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten, thanks for your valuable input. Initially we had thought of taking the same approach that you have suggested.
But then we realized that the approach will have a major performance issue on following considerations:

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: Normally for a Solution of about 1GB code(100 plus projects) the average time the code 
"MSBuildWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result" takes to load the solution is 52sec. For a real life scenario, clubbing projects from different solutions into one solution and then pening the Solution is going to take much higher time. 

It will be very helpful if you can share your experience on the performance consideration with the approach in context of the scenario i have mentioned above. Looking forward to hear from you. 
Thanks again for sparing your valuable time.

Comment: Well, like I said I had a *similar* problem, not the same. In my case, my problem needed solving correctly. Doing that efficiently was, as always, a nice to have, but not required. Solving the problem correctly was the only requirement. And that necessitated the approach we took. Whether it does for you too, I leave that up to you to decide.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski,  I have added more details to my problem statement.  Please let me know if you need any more information. 

Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: @SLaks, I have added more details to my problem statement. Please let me know if you need any more information. Looking forward to your responses

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a metadata reference.

Comment: @SLaks, sorry for coming late on this thread. I dint get you. Can you please elaborate on "missing a metadata reference" ?

As i have mentioned it earlier, I am loading one solution using MSBuildWorkspac.OpenSolutionAsync() and then I am iterating through each Project of the solution and through project I am iterating through each Document object.

In one of the Documents (Compilation Unit), I have a reference to a type which is defined in a completely different solution and refereed using a .dll reference . 
We want to resolve this Type along with its file path where it is defined.

Comment: Roslyn probably couldn't resolve the reference to that DLL.  Look at the diagnostics for the compilation, or look at the properties of the reference.